sha256checksum - how to compare local file with checksum of the remote original
I have a local file file1 as well as the sha256 checksum of the original file.
The remote is a rhel8 server, local tool sha256sum inside of a git bash on a Windows10 Laptop.
For the love of god I seem to be unable to compare those too in a reasonable manner.
on the remote I get
~> sha256sum file1
55dcd0a7046a24e5ee296d1481d6f787b1956d138bbfb6e44ca8591006367f27  file1

so my question is ... how to I compare that locally created sum with the checksum I took on the remote?
I would assume there must be a way to do this with the sha256sum command itself which then somhow outputs checksum matches or checksum differs
or is it really that you have to rely on your eysight to compare those 2 or creation of a extra text files containing each checksum and execute a diff on them?
the best way I can come up with is
echo [sha of the remote file] ; sha256sum file1
55dcd0a7046a24e5ee296d1481d6f787b1956d138bbfb6e44ca8591006367f27
55dcd0a7046a24e5ee296d1481d6f787b1956d138bbfb6e44ca8591006367f27 *file1

... and then compare those 2 lines using my bare eyesight.
is there nothing better?
the manual says
       -c, --check
              read SHA256 sums from the FILEs and check them

but what does that practically mean?
sha256sum file1 --check [sha of the remote file] would sound logical to me but does not work.
Neither does
:~> sha256sum file1 --check
sha256sum: file1: no properly formatted SHA256 checksum lines found


The path is wrong, you need to adjust the path or regain the checksum of file1

can you be a little more specific? I don't get what path I need to adjust and in which way.

You need to put the checksum line in a file and use that:

put 55dcd0a7046a24e5ee296d1481d6f787b1956d138bbfb6e44ca8591006367f27  file1 into a file, say checksum.txt, next to file1.
sha256sum -c checksum.txt.

alternatively, sha256sum can also read checksum files from standard input:
echo "55dcd0a7046a24e5ee296d1481d6f787b1956d138bbfb6e44ca8591006367f27  file1" | sha256sum -c -


thx @Marcus Müller. Spot on. I wonder really though how the authors of sha256sum (whom I am really thankfull of for creating this in the first place) believe anybody would come up with this by reading their manpage. Or is it me being really, really stubborn?

a bit of the latter? I mean, I went just in there and read "Oh -c checks the checksums from FILE, that means I need to supply it with a file containing the checksum. How would I create such a file? Ah, that must be the output of sha256sum without the -c"

You can even go ssh remote sha256sum file1 | sha256sum -c

After the comment by Z0OM, I found a workable solution on the youtube university. And the answer is grep:
~$ sha256sum file1 | grep 5dcd0a7046a24e5ee296d1481d6f787b1956d138bbfb6e44ca8591006367f27

If this is successful, the output of your local SHA command matches the remote hash.
